# Password don't match angularJs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I don't seem to understand why ng-show is failing to display this validation when the passwords don't match. What am I missing?

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input ng-required="true" name="username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="model.user.username" type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Username">
      <p class="errorValidationText" ng-show="myForm.username.$invalid && myForm.username.$touched">Please pick a username between 3 - 10 characters.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input ng-required="true" name="password" ng-minlength="4" ng-model="model.user.password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      <p class="errorValidationText" ng-show="myForm.password.$invalid && myForm.password.$touched">Password should contain atleast 4 characters.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input ng-required="true" name="verifyPassword" ng-minlength="4" ng-model="model.user.verifyPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="verify-password" placeholder="Verify Password">
      <p class="errorValidationText" ng-show="(myForm.verifyPassword.value != '') && (myForm.password.value != myForm.verifypassword.value)">Passwords don't match.</p>
    </div>

 <button ng-disabled="myForm.username.$invalid || myForm.password.$invalid || myForm.verifyPassword" ng-click="model.register(model.user)" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</button>

  </form>
```

Thanks!!
I've reffered the other solutions, none of the existing questions are similar to what I am doing.

Comment: You can't use the HTML delimiters of your parameter (namely, `"`) inside the parameter itself. Use simple quotes instead (`'`).

Comment: @Blackhole is correct.
`(myForm.verifyPassword.value != '') && (myForm.password.value !== myForm.verifypassword.value)`

Comment: @BlackHole - Thanks! But that still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please add the rest of your code, there is probably something wrong there

Comment: @MarioLamacchia I've pasted the rest of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The myForm object doesn't have the input values, you can see that with `{{myForm}}`. Use the value from ngModel instead:

```
<p ng-show="(user.model.verifyPassword != '') && (user.model.password != user.model.verifyPassword)">Passwords don't match</p>
```

Also notice that if your input is not valid, ngModel won't set the value: `user.model.verifyPassword != ''` is going to be always true, since you set `ng-minlength=4`.

Another tip: `ng` attributes make sense only if you evaluate a scope variable, `ng-required="true"` is the same as `required="required"`.

Comment: Makes sense!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`myForm.verifyPassword.value` casing is different in your statement `myForm.verifypassword.value`

I made up an example as I didn't have your code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myForm = {
    password: '',
    verifyPassword: ''
  };

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log('success');
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  Password:
  <input type="password" ng-model="myForm.password">
  <br>Verify Password:
  <input type="password" ng-model="myForm.verifyPassword">
  <br>

  <p ng-show="(myForm.verifyPassword != '') && (myForm.password != myForm.verifyPassword)">Passwords don't match</p>

  <button>Submit</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Fixed the casing. But the <p> doesn't show even after that change.

Comment: @user1799214 I also removed .value from the end of each property

Comment: Right, but doing that makes the validation show up even before the field is touched. The <p> tag shows up as soon as the page loads.

Comment: @user1799214 In my example I initialise the form with my desired starting values